# mysql insert not working in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am developing a web app using nodejs and mysql. The mysql connection is working as fine but query is not excecuting and not showing any errors. My code ishown below. Pls help me.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database : "db"
});

con.connect(function(err){
if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');

    return;
} else {


var time = Date.now();
var post  = {userphone: "user", senderphone: "to1", message: "msg", time:time};             
var query = con.query('INSERT INTO chat SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    console.log('db added');
    console.log(query.sql);
            });
        console.log('Connection established');
    }
});

con.end(function(err) {
    // The connection is terminated gracefully
    // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
    // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});
```

Comment: INSERT SET is not standard sql

Comment: I use VALUES instead of SET But same problem.

Comment: Did you checked what is coming in err variable? I mean here - query = con.query(..INSERT QUERY.., post, function(err, result) { if(err){throw err;} else{ .... }

Comment: You have to use `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (value1, value2)`

Comment: @ManikandanS Not showing any error

Comment: What is the log output? Try `console.log(err)` within the callback of your query.

Comment: @modsfabio not getting any result

Comment: @str not showing anything

Comment: make sure you add string values with `'`. Example `... VALUES ('some string', 'another string')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to print the `err` in the connection it shows:

```
    ~/Documents/src : $ node testInsert.js 
Connection established
{ [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }
db added
INSERT INTO chat SET `userphone` = 'user', `senderphone` = 'to1', `message` = 'msg', `time` = 1493132496360
```

Clearly your database connection is getting closed before executing query. You need to move that close connection block into query block to force it's execution after query like this:

```
con.connect(function(err){
  console.log('Connection established');
  if(err){
      console.log('Error connecting to Db');
      return;
  } else {
    var time = Date.now();
    var post  = {userphone: "user", senderphone: "to1", message: "msg", time:time};             
    var query = con.query('INSERT INTO chat SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log('db added');
        console.log(query.sql);
        con.end(function(err) {
            // The connection is terminated gracefully
            // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
            // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
        });
    });
  }
});
```

When i ran it insertion was successful:

```
~/Documents/src : $ node testInsert.js 
Connection established
db added
INSERT INTO chat SET `userphone` = 'user', `senderphone` = 'to1', `message` = 'msg', `time` = 1493132632444
mysql> SELECT * FROM chat;
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| userphone | senderphone | time                | message |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| user      | to1         | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | msg     |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```